# Java - Run game again if button is clicked, but game is still in progress

Tags: java

I have a Window class that extends JFrame. This Window has an instance of the Game class that extends JPanel. The Window houses the Game in a JPanel and displays it accordingly. The Game runs with a run() method, till the endgame criteria is met.

I have to implement a button (in JMenu) that restarts the game whenever I click it whether or not game has finished.

How can I restart the game from the Window class? I tried to add an EventListener to the JMenu button and I managed to get the game to restart when I clicked and the following happened:
The game restarted (ran fine in the background) but it did not display anything (it showed the last 'frame' of the previous game). After the EventListener scope ended - because the new game I called from there ended - the last 'frame' of the new game was shown. In short: for some reason it doesn't display anything when called from the EventListener's scope.

Barebones Window class:

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Game game;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu menu;
JMenuItem newGame, highScores;

public Window() {

    //Menu
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
    highScores = new JMenuItem("Highscores");
    newGame.addActionListener(this);
    highScores.addActionListener(this);
    menu.add(newGame);
    menu.add(highScores);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //Components
    counter.setFont(new Font("Monaco", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    counter.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel abovePane = new JPanel();
    abovePane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


    abovePane.add(counter, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    abovePane.add(timerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(abovePane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    game = new Game();
    getContentPane().add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation(dim.width / 2 - getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - getSize().height / 2);
    setVisible(true);

    game.initGame();
    addKeyListener(new KeyboardListener());
    game.run();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == newGame) {
        game = new Game();
        getContentPane().add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        game.initGame();
        game.run();
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any system to dispose/stop the game loop? I don't see anything being done to stop the previous game class if that needs to be done.

Comment: @Ryan_DS The game loop runs while it's 'end' variable is false. I change it to true in the EventListener before I call game = new Game(); I just forgot to include it here. Is there a better way to stop that game?